# If Heroku runs cron daily, do we still need 'if time.now.hour...`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, heroku

I'm trying to figure out how Heroku daily cron works, specifically in this way:

As per Heroku's own [cron docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron), cron tasks are often written like this:

```
if Time.now.hour == 0 # run at midnight
  User.send_reminders
end
```

Well, what happens if I set up cron at a time other than midnight? At least from my debugging, it seems that whenever Heroku cron runs (nearly always not at midnight), the above section of code is simply ignored.

Is it good practice to eliminate the time element from `cron.rake` and have the simple statement `User.send_reminders`, to be executed whenever that document is run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Heroku FAQ says this:

> Cron jobs execute based on when you
>   enable the add-on. If you enable the
>   hourly add-on at 9:35 in the morning,
>   for instance, the cron job will run at
>   35 minutes past the hour every hour;
>   if you enabled the daily add-on at the
>   same time, it would run every day at
>   9:35.

I believe this is how my daily cron jobs run, although I didn't pay too much attention to that. I don't have any time checks in my daily cron task.

The time check in the Heroku example would be useful when using hourly cron, but not when using daily.